# Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadd00d (code=1), thread 15725 (Compiler)

Tags: android

I wrote the application without NDK using and it can crash with random actions with the following error:

```
12-20 14:21:13.590 15718-15725 A/jazz: mediatek/protect/dalvik/vm/jazz/dexlang/dex_lang-inl.h:2415] void jazz::DexLang<BitcodeGenerator>::EmitInstruction(const jazz::AIR&) [with BitcodeGenerator = jazz::dixieland::BitcodeGenerator] unimplemented not
12-20 14:21:13.590 15718-15725 E/dalvikvm: VM aborting
12-20 14:21:13.590 15718-15725 A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadd00d (code=1), thread 15725 (Compiler)
12-20 14:21:13.591 15718-15725 A/libc: Send stop signal to pid:15718 in debugger_signal_handler
```

I'm running the app on different emulators and devices, but on my device it constantly crashing.

Device:

```
PHONE_MODEL=JY-G4S
ANDROID_VERSION=4.2.2
BUILD=TIME=1402319802000
FINGERPRINT=JIAYU/S8/S8:4.2.2/JDQ39/1402319714:user/test-keys
HARDWARE=mt6592
USER=scm
HOST=vanzo68
DEVICE=S8
TAGS=test-keys
MODEL=JY-G4S
BOOTLOADER=unknown
VERSION.CODENAME=REL
VERSION.INCREMENTAL=eng.scm.1402319714
VERSION.RELEASE=4.2.2
VERSION.SDK_INT=17
VERSION.RESOURCES_SDK_INT=17
VERSION.SDK=17
CPU_ABI=armeabi-v7a
CPU_ABI2=armeabi
MANUFACTURER=JYT
BRAND=JIAYU
TYPE=user
PRODUCT=S8
```

Can I fix this error programmatically without flashing the device?

Comment: Did you get any further with this?

Comment: @korrekorre From the comment [on github](https://github.com/cgeo/cgeo/issues/3822#issuecomment-45843291) this issue can't be fixed programmatically.

Comment: It seems like adding this property 'android.enableD8=true' in our ./gradle/gradle.properties was causing this issue. When removing it, it all started working again on the troublesome devices (pre lollipop) where we was having the crash.

Comment: @korrekorre This solution helped me. Please, add it as an answer and I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing I found is that using the next generation (D8) dex compiler might cause this issue. From my experience it seems like adding the property `android.enableD8=true` in your ./gradle/gradle.properties file might cause this issue on some pre lollipop devices.

After removing it again, it all started working on the troublesome devices where we was seeing the crash before.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the custom mediatek Dalvik JIT did not implement the dex "not" instruction. D8 generates this instruction and DX most likely did not. We will workaround the VM bug by never generating a "not" instruction in D8 when targeting Dalvik VMs.

We are pushing out the fix for Android Studio 3.1 so that this will not be a problem once Android Studio 3.1 goes stable.

Fix here: https://r8-review.googlesource.com/c/r8/+/16880

Comment: That's great. Thank you for the clarification and fixing that bug.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR Don't use D8 with Android Gradle Build Plugin 3.0.x.**

I catch this JIT Compiler crash on Lenovo P70-A in our app. In our case the error was:

```
F/jazz    (11964): mediatek/protect/dalvik/vm/jazz/dexlang/dex_lang-inl.h:2523] void jazz::DexLang<BitcodeGenerator>::EmitInstruction(const jazz::AIR&) [with BitcodeGenerator = jazz::dixieland::BitcodeGenerator] unimplemented not
E/dalvikvm(11964): VM aborting
F/libc    (11964): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x00002ebc (code=-6), thread 11970 (Compiler)
```

followed by crash dump:

```
I/DEBUG   (12113): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG   (12113): Build fingerprint: 'Lenovo/P70-A/P70-A:4.4.4/KOT49H/P70-A_S142_161230_16G_ROW:user/release-keys'
I/DEBUG   (12113): pid: 11964, tid: 11970, name: Compiler  >>> com.myapp <<<
I/DEBUG   (12113): signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
I/DEBUG   (12113):     r0 00000000  r1 00002ec2  r2 00000006  r3 00000000
I/DEBUG   (12113):     r4 00000006  r5 00000000  r6 00002ec2  r7 0000010c
I/DEBUG   (12113):     r8 85d1ea6d  r9 40159bd4  sl 76dd58ac  fp 8283af64
I/DEBUG   (12113):     ip fffd1aa8  sp 76dd5630  lr 40109431  pc 40117dec  cpsr 000f0010
I/DEBUG   (12113):
I/DEBUG   (12113): backtrace:
I/DEBUG   (12113):     #00  pc 00025dec  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
I/DEBUG   (12113):     #01  pc 0001742d  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+64)
I/DEBUG   (12113):     #02  pc 00017625  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
I/DEBUG   (12113):     #03  pc 0001633b  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (12113):     #04  pc 0002569c  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
I/DEBUG   (12113):     #05  pc 0008a8fd  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmAbort+80)
I/DEBUG   (12113):     #06  pc 0015a1e9  /system/lib/libdvm.so (jazz::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+576)
I/DEBUG   (12113):     #07  pc 0014f49d  /system/lib/libdvm.so (jazz::DexLang<jazz::dixieland::BitcodeGenerator>::EmitInstruction(jazz::AIR const&)+1016)
I/DEBUG   (12113):     #08  pc 0014f60b  /system/lib/libdvm.so (jazz::dixieland::Frontend::Compile(unsigned int, jazz::AIRMethod const&)+346)
I/DEBUG   (12113):     #09  pc 00153925  /system/lib/libdvm.so (jazz::dixieland::SubCompiler::Compile(unsigned int, jazz::AIRMethod const&)+32)
I/DEBUG   (12113):     #10  pc 00154443  /system/lib/libdvm.so (jazz::Jazz::Compile(jazz::CompilationUnit&)+126)
I/DEBUG   (12113):     #11  pc 00140d4d  /system/lib/libdvm.so (jazz::Compiler::JitMethod(Method const&, jazz::jex::CompiledRawCode const*&, jazz::jex::CompiledRawCode const*&)+164)
I/DEBUG   (12113):     #12  pc 0011873d  /system/lib/libdvm.so (jazzDoJITCompile(JitJazzMethodDescription const&, JitTranslationInfo&)+128)
I/DEBUG   (12113):     #13  pc 000f204f  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCompilerDoWork(CompilerWorkOrder*)+50)
I/DEBUG   (12113):     #14  pc 000d9f77  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (12113):     #15  pc 000a0485  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (12113):     #16  pc 0000d838  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
I/DEBUG   (12113):
I/DEBUG   (12113): stack:
...
```

As mentioned in other answers it was caused by D8 implementation which is using `not` instruction in Dalvik binary code, but JIT Compiler on this device not support this instruction. Solution is to disable D8 in compilation by removing `android.enableD8=true` from `gradle.properties` for AGP 3.0.x. Stable AGP 3.1 will contain [fix for this](https://r8-review.googlesource.com/c/r8/+/16880).

**Edit: Probably this happen on the devices with Mediatek SOC where is running KitKat.**